# How do I change power button functionality to Suspend in stead of Power Off on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, 20.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

#### Summary

How do I change power button functionality to Suspend instead of Power Off on Ubuntu 20.04?

#### Details

Just updated Ubuntu to 20.04 from 18.04.
Pressing the power button used to Suspend instead of Turning off the computer, but after update it powers off, not suspend.

I don't see a GUI option to change power button functionality in Ubuntu 20.4?
Anyone knows how to go about it?

Comment: With the command `systemd-analyze blame` you can see what process(es) take(s) a long time to boot.

Take a look at `gnome tweaks` for the power-button issue.

Comment: Generally AskUbuntu expects one question per question. I've removed the two additional questions from your question, to focus it on what the title says. Feel free to ask the other two questions as new questions. You can access the history of your question by pressing the *Edited ... ago* below your question.

Answer (score 5):

This is a screen shot of a fresh install of 22.04...

[image]

Comment: These settings don't show up in 22.04 for me. The only thing there is "Show battery percentage" :(

Comment: @IanSmith That's interesting - are you running Ubuntu on mare metal, or over a hypervisor of some type?

Answer (score 1):

Install dconf editor and set power-button-action to value: "nothing"

Location: /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/power-button-action